# Question on the proof of de Rham's theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, de-rham-cohomology

In John M. Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*, in chapter 18, he seeks to prove the de Rham theorem. Step 4 of the proof is to show that if $M$ is a smooth manifold with a de Rham basis, then $M$ satisfies the de Rham theorem ($M$ is "de Rham"). In his proof of this claim he states: Let $\{U_\alpha\}$ is such a basis, and $f:M\to \mathbb R$ is a smooth exhaustion function for $M$, and define the following subsets of $M$: $$A_m := \{q\in M| m \le f(q) \le m+1\}$$$$A'_m:=\{q\in M|m -\frac 12 < f(q) < m+\frac32\}.$$ Then, for each $q\in M$, there is a basis open subset containing $q$ and contained in $A'_m$ such that all of these open subsets cover $A_m$. He offers no justification for these statements, and I have beeen unable to justify them myself.

Comment: Where are you stuck? It looks elementary to us.

Comment: I've figured it out, for the most part. It contains such an open set for each $q$ because the function $f$ is required to be continuous, so the preimage of any open set in $\mathbb R$ is open in $M$, and these open sets are all contained in $A'_m$. However, how could one show that the preimages of the open subsets of $\mathbb R$ are members of the de Rham basis for $M$?

Comment: No, the point is that by your argument $A_m$ and $A_m'$ are open sets. Now use the definition of a basis.

Comment: Yes, I found the (rather trivial) statement on wikipedia: If $q$ is a point contained in an open subset $U$, then there exists a basis element containing $q$ and contained in $U$. Thus, each point $q$ is contained in an element of the de Rham basis.